How to put Turtles inside a [GIS extension] Shapefile in Netlogo?
I am trying to create turtles inside a shapefile. I have imported the GIS extension and loaded the shapefile. I am now trying to generate the turtles into the shapefile boundary as they are generated also outside of it which I don't want.
Here are the sections of the code containing the shapefile and the creation of the turtles. I have currently have
Loading Dataset code
Next, when I created the turtle
Turtle creation
I have tried gis:create-turtles-inside-polygon within this section and gis:create-turtles-inside but i get the error that it expects GIS:CREATE-TURTLES-INSIDE-POLYGON expected 3 inputs. I currently have it set to setxy random-xcor random-ycor as that is the only thing I got to work.

Do not post images of text on Stack Overflow. Text is text: copy it, paste it into your question, format it as code.

Are you trying to put the turtles all inside one big polygon, or anyplace within all the polygons, or a certain number of turtles within each polygon?
Depending on which of those you are trying to do, gis:create-turtles-inside-polygon could be what you need; did you follow the example code in the User Manual? The error statement indicates that you just didn't write the code statement properly.
Another approach is to use gis:apply-coverage to set a patch variable of all the patches that are inside the polygons. For example, if your shapefile has a polygon property "veg-type" you could give the patches a variable "veg" and use:
gis:apply-coverage MyDataset "veg-type" veg
Now, any patches within the shapefile will have a non-zero value of veg while the patches outside the shapefile will have veg = 0. So you can create turtles and tell them to move to one of the cells with veg != 0. You might need to use small patches to make this work well. (I use a global variable "world-resolution" that controls patch size, e.g., 1.0 meters per patch-width.)
